# could not be able to work with list control in flex 4.5

Tags: flex4.5, flex-mobile

I want to be selected that new Item in list when I give new value to dataProvider but it selects the item that was firstly selected, and how to make that selected permanently on App start up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You if want to select the list item after added to dataProvider. Probably you follow this

```
list.selectedIndex = list.dataProvider.length -1;
```

Sometimes if you added at desired position like

```
 list.dataProvider.setItemAt(obj,2); 

 list.selectedIndex = 2
```

If you want to selected item permanently on App start up.(Make sure that your array collections bind-able to list)

```
    public function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    callLater(function():void
    {
        list.selectedIndex = list.dataProvider.length -1;
        list.ensureIndexIsVisible(list.selectedIndex); // Viewport
    });
}
```